# How to show chooser Intent with my own android app on click of WhatsApp location?

Tags: android, android-intent, geolocation, whatsapp

If there's a WhatsApp chat which has location shared, when clicked it shows a chooser intent with some set of applications. I want to write an intent filter so that my application will also be listed there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by supporting **implicit** `intent` to your `Activity`.
Define `intent-filter` to `Activity` to which you want to open after clicking to your Application from options.

```
<activity android:name=".BrowserActivitiy"
          android:label="@string/app_name">

      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <data android:scheme="http"/>
         <data android:scheme="geo"/>
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To know more about **Intents** and **Intent filters** go to official website.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Manifest file (Particular activity):

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:scheme="geo" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.