# How to show chooser Intent with my own android app on click of whatsapp profile image share

Tags: android, nativescript, intentfilter

I’m trying to show my native script app as a chooser intent when whats app profile image share button on top right was clicked, and want to know how to handle those things within my app. Where do I need to add the code to display image inside my app upon click my app in the chooser intent?

i'have found similar issue here 
[How to show chooser Intent with my own android app on click of WhatsApp location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631121/how-to-show-chooser-intent-with-my-own-android-app-on-click-of-whatsapp-location)
where it is given for map, but i want it for image.

I expect to open the image of whats app profile, on tap of intent and display that image inside my app. and let the user choose save or cancel in user defined folder structure. can anyone guide me?

i tried this to handle incoming image but its not working.

```
let intent = android.getIntent();
let action = android.intent.getAction();
let type = android.intent.getType();

if (android.intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
        handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
    } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
    }
} else if (android.intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
    if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
        handleSendMultipleImages(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
    }
} else {
    // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
}

function handleSendImage(intent) {
    var imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(android.intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    console.log("-----image uri-------");
    console.log(imageUri);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update your `intent-filter` for NativeScript Activity to let system know your Activity can handle selection of an  image.

```
<activity android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"...>  

  ...

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
  </intent-filter>   

</activity>
```

Comment: it's the exact answer, now if i tap that on whatsapp it is just opening my app. may be it is navigating to app.js first. how to handle that image in app.js if i'm right.

Comment: i tried something like i have updated but its giving android.getIntent of undefined.

Comment: What is `android` in your code? Also you are suppose to send the image to Whatsapp back, that's what you were asking for, am I right?

Comment: no i dont need to send back to whatsapp. upon i choose my app on chooser intent of whatsapp. i mean when i tap share btn on whatsapp my app will also be listed in that chooser intent. so when i tap it, my app will open and i need to display that image to user on my main screen in my app, thats it.

Comment: @ i dont know what is android in my code. i though, to access native android services i need to use android like you have used "android.intent.action.SEND"

Comment: `.getIntent()` is a method on Activity. Wait for activity started event and get intent from the activity.

Comment: yes this was the answer, but i stuck in next line "if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
" what is Intent here i tried every possibility but not find what it is. i'm referring this link https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive